# PHP/JavaScript Security - Is JS security worthless?

Tags: javascript, php, security

people!

I'm thinking about the architecture of an [ERP System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning), which will be a [Single-Page App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). I'll show you my thought process and how I arrived at the questions.

## PHP Structure and Reasoning

- 0. MySQL
- 1. Database Core
- 2. ERP Modules (User Auth is in here)
- 3. I/O
- 4. Request

**How it works:** `DBCore` will provide the API to query the database, `ERP` will be all the bussiness modules we need, `I/O` will take care of translating `ERP` responses to HTML format and `Request` will be the gate between Server and Client, translating POST arrays into `I/O` arrays.

**Module limits:** Modules can only talk to the module right after it or right before it. So, `DBCore` will only talk to `MySQL` or `ERP`, `ERP` can only talk to `DBCore` and `I/O`... and so on.

**Security Reasoning:** All modules will have **one** input and **one** output source. So my idea is that I can control exactly what goes in and out through a rigid set of rules at each IO point. This means that way before reaching sensitive data on `ERP` or `DBCore` modules, the input will be filtered by 2 different filters and is in it's way to be filtered two more times (one in the `Auth` module inside `ERP` and one in the `DBCore` module with `mysqli::real_escape_string()`).

All of that will be outside the Public WWW folder. To communicate with the App, there will be one file in the WWW folder, **index.php**. This page will boot the system and start a Request if it gets POSTed. Then it simply echoes the response back to the client.

#### 1. Is this architecture secure?

#### 2. Do those IO bottlenecks increase my (potential*) security?

*Potential because if the filters are crap, then security will be crap.

## JavaScript Reasoning

Then I started thinking about how the JavaScript would work. My first idea was that JS would only take care of basic behavior of the system (clicking, hovering, animations, positioning, sorting, etc...). But then I started searching for JavaScript security and found some people saying I should treat user input on cases like:

```
var data = '<div class="data">' + someUserInput + '</div>';
$('#someContainer').html(data);
```

The reason is that I shouldn't trust my user. I get that. I don't trust the user - that's why I'll be checking the userspace data at every IO point in the server. But then, If JS is only on the client side and if the guy is hacking JS, the only thing he's gonna hack is **his own view of the system**, right? So JS "security" becomes useless.

Put it this way: **If** my PHP Code is so good that no data will go unfiltered and that those filters are 100% secure, JS security loses it's value, right?

In other words, I can do (securely):

```
var foo = $('input#foo-input').val();

$.post('foo.php', {action: foo}, function(r) {
    $('div#foo').html(r);
});
```

#### 3. Does JS security loses its value since PHP will do security checks?

Furthermore, if all my PHP code is crap and I do have all of the **best** JS security, it still can be bypassed just by looking at code, right? I mean, we do have all these cool JS Console on browsers now that can do all sorts of things. He can open a JS Console and POST anything he wants with a simple $.post(), right? Then we're back to step one where PHP needs to filter userspace data...

Which leads me to the latent question in my head:

#### 4. Is JS Security worthless?

I mean, is it just paranoia? I get that the more points you do security checks the better, but when you think up a world where the best and most determined hacker is trying to hack your system (assuming he's not going to exploit your server directly), minifying, obscuring and securing JS code becomes useless - after all, the guy has all the code in his hands to analyze, he just needs patience.

Comment: It's one more thing the user has to get around if he's trying to break your security. And it also reduces load on your server, because unintended errors can be detected on the client before bothering the server.

Comment: It could also help with the user experience. The page doesn't have to reload everytime they make a mistake, if you have validation checks in JavaScipt .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's both. The server shouldn't trust the client because people can inject javascript and override your javascript logic. Indeed, people may not even run your javascript and simply send you bad data (think about a shell script accessing you website using curl or wget).

At the same time, your javascript shouldn't trust data from the server because people may do an MITM attack and inject stuff into your page. MITM does not need to be a hacker on your network. It could also be a bad/malicious browser plugin. Even without an MITM attacker, it should protect itself from your own mistakes in the server code. The majority of security exploits are bugs.

So you need both. The PHP code should sanitize your data. The javascript code should not simply `.innerHTML` or `eval()` stuff from the server without checking.

Comment: Can I securely encrypt messages in JS to prevent MITM attacks (even from Browser plugins)? Since the key will be exposed in the source code anyone could look, right? Even a plugin...

Comment: @EnzoFerber Simple answer: No. Everything you do in JS can be easily changed.

Comment: For network attacks you'd want to use HTTPS. For protection in the browser there are ways to hide variables by using closures. For protecting communications to your server from the page, it's not practical. Sure, it may be possible to replace XMLHttpRequest so that foreign scripts on your page can not use it. But they can still create an `img` or `script` tag to communicate with your server.

Comment: So JavaScript is a security hole. For what I understand, everything I do with JS will only be a little obstacle to an attacker. Are there any good resources you could point me that address PHP/JS security issues?

Comment: I don't know of a single source. Just be aware of best practices for you language/framework and always make sure your libraries are up to date. It also helps if you use libraries/frameworks that are popular because they get hacked more so have more bug fixes compared to less popular libraries. Security is not a single issue, it's many things. Even HTTPS is a security hole if you configure your web server wrong.